# Very simple Javascript loop to create event listeners, returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-events

I have a list of cities, and when I click on a link, I'd like some particular Javascript to run. JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uWYRW/5/

```
var cities = [
    ["new-york", 45, 90, 15]
    ["london", 20, 30, 15]
];

for (i = 0, length = cities.length; i < length; i++) {
    $("#"+cities[i][0]).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(cities[i][0])
    });
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

> "undefined' is not an object".

Please can somebody explain where the problem lies?

Comment: which line do you have an error on?

Comment: add `console.log(cities.length, i)` to your click handler and you will see the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression):

```
for (i = 0, length = cities.length; i < length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $("#"+cities[i][0]).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(cities[i][0])
        });
    })(i);
}
```

This is because once the loop is done, the value of `i` will be `cities.length` for all of the `click` listeners.

Also, you are missing a comma in your 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cities = [
    ["new-york", 45, 90, 15], // <-- that comma was missing
    ["london", 20, 30, 15]
];
```

Notice the comma you forgot to seperate in the array :)

Comment: This won't solve the problem though.

Comment: Three upvotes for answer that doesn't solve the problem. Lucky you! FYI, if the OP had the comment missing in their actual code, it would not even run but throw a syntax error. Since it appears that the code *does* run, the comma must be in the OP's real code.